# android : tabhost not rendering tabs

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I have a simple activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TabHost tabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();
        tabHost.newTabSpec("a");
        tabHost.newTabSpec("b");
        tabHost.newTabSpec("c");
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is xml for its view definition

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="activities.MainActivity"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="#ff0007ff"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:background="#ff122dff"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I understand the view for tabhost has blank content but I expected view of atleast tabs being rendered when this activity gets launched

however I see a blank screen for this activity, what am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: u just initialize tabhost, try to add to tabhost

Comment: thank you @Jai, do you mean add TabSpec to tabHost ?

Comment: **Try this already answer about tabhost.**

[Click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024259/cant-change-tag-of-fragment-page/28026608#28026608

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-activity-android-with-a-tabhost-view/27990

Comment: Thank you @Jai Rajesh, but that uses ViewPager I just want to use `TabHost`

Comment: @Thank you IntelliJ that post uses single activity for each tab, can I delegate to different activities on tab selection ?

Comment: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add each tab item to the tab widget as below:

```
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();

TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabs.newTabSpec("tab1");
tab1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
tab1.setIndicator("Tab 1");
tabHost.addTab(tab1);
```

Answer (score 0):

tabs are implemented using Fragments. In xml, instead of TabHost you need to use android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost class. In java you need  to extend FragmentActivity and also need to add tabs in FragmentTabHost manually. complete example is given [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).